# Find Next (F3) doesn't work properly in Visual Studio 2019, jumps to another document abruptly

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I use CTRL + F3 to select the string where cursor is and then F3 to find next and SHIFT + F3 to find previous a lot but it's broken in Visual Studio 2019.

It selects the string where the cursor is at CTRL + F3. Then next F3 search that string in document but pressing F3 again jumps to another document and starts to search completely different string.

Even if I pick a string that's used many times in the current document, it just jumps to another doc after the 2nd F3.

I want to be able to search only in current document but I can't find that entry in keyboard shortcut customization. I don't like global search anyways even if it was working fine, I only want search in current document.

How can I fix this?

Visual Studio 2019 version is Version 16.5.4

Answer (score 1):

I am going to post this as a solution.

Press 'next' (the array key button) on search bar has fixed it.

Press CTRL + F3 and current string under cursor get selected and the search bar also popups. Instead of press F3 now, press the arrow key on search bar (which is to search next) and that seems have reset functionality.

Now F3 and SHIFT + F3, all works as desirable and they search only in current document. Doesn't continue search into other documents which is also great.